# SQL view slowing dramatically on certain parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

I've got an SQL view which seems to be grinding to a halt now that I'm reaching higher values on one of my parameters.

It appears to be the FKID_Operation (from the tbl_Operations table). This is fine if we search on basically anything up to 1504, but as soon as we hit 1505 it slows dramatically. I can't think why - the field is a regular int so it should be able to take that value (and if it couldn't, it shouldn't have allowed it anyway, and it is in there) and everything is indexed correctly. I think the problem lies in trying to retrieve records from the tbl_Schedules table - it works fine without that - but again, can't think why. Everything is present and correct, and it works fine with values added afterwards.

The code is:

```
SELECT     dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.PKID_PhysicalAsset, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.FKID_Contract, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L1_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L2_Name, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L3_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare1, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare2, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare3, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare4, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare5, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Deleted AS Expr1, dbo.tbl_Operations.PKID_Operation, dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Operation AS WhatOp, 
                  dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Team, dbo.tbl_Operations.Deleted AS Expr2, dbo.tbl_Schedules.PKID_Schedule, dbo.tbl_Schedules.FKID_Operation, 
                  dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom, dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo, dbo.tbl_Schedules.Deleted, CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom AS VARCHAR(11)) 
                  + ' to ' + CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo AS VARCHAR(11)) AS Combined, YEAR(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom) AS MyYear
FROM         dbo.tbl_Operations INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset ON dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_PhysicalAsset = dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.PKID_PhysicalAsset INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_Schedules ON dbo.tbl_Operations.PKID_Operation = dbo.tbl_Schedules.FKID_Operation
GROUP BY dbo.tbl_Schedules.PKID_Schedule, dbo.tbl_Schedules.FKID_Operation, dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom, dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo, 
                  CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom AS VARCHAR(11)) + ' to ' + CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo AS VARCHAR(11)), dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.FKID_Contract, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L1_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L2_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L3_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare1, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare2, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare3, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare4, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare5, dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Team, dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Operation, 
                  YEAR(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom), dbo.tbl_Schedules.Deleted, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Deleted, dbo.tbl_Operations.Deleted, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.PKID_PhysicalAsset, dbo.tbl_Operations.PKID_Operation
HAVING      (dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.tbl_Operations.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.FKID_Contract = 58) AND 
                  (dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Operation = 1505)
```

Comment: Why are you using a having clause instead of a where clause?

Comment: Hmm... would that help speed things up? I've come across similar things in the past.

Comment: @MichaelBell `having` needs to gather all data and filter out the results that don't match, `where` filters out the data beforehand

Comment: Just having a bit of trouble putting where instead of having, but should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just convert the having clause to a where clause.

```
SELECT     dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.PKID_PhysicalAsset, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.FKID_Contract, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L1_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L2_Name, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L3_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare1, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare2, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare3, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare4, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare5, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Deleted AS Expr1, dbo.tbl_Operations.PKID_Operation, dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Operation AS WhatOp, 
                  dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Team, dbo.tbl_Operations.Deleted AS Expr2, dbo.tbl_Schedules.PKID_Schedule, dbo.tbl_Schedules.FKID_Operation, 
                  dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom, dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo, dbo.tbl_Schedules.Deleted, CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom AS VARCHAR(11)) 
                  + ' to ' + CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo AS VARCHAR(11)) AS Combined, YEAR(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom) AS MyYear
FROM         dbo.tbl_Operations INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset ON dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_PhysicalAsset = dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.PKID_PhysicalAsset INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_Schedules ON dbo.tbl_Operations.PKID_Operation = dbo.tbl_Schedules.FKID_Operation
WHERE (dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.tbl_Operations.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.FKID_Contract = 58) AND 
                  (dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Operation = 1505)
GROUP BY dbo.tbl_Schedules.PKID_Schedule, dbo.tbl_Schedules.FKID_Operation, dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom, dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo, 
                  CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom AS VARCHAR(11)) + ' to ' + CAST(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedTo AS VARCHAR(11)), dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.FKID_Contract, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L1_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L2_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.L3_Name, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare1, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare2, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare3, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare4, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Spare5, dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Team, dbo.tbl_Operations.FKID_Operation, 
                  YEAR(dbo.tbl_Schedules.SchedFrom), dbo.tbl_Schedules.Deleted, dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.Deleted, dbo.tbl_Operations.Deleted, 
                  dbo.tbl_PhysicalAsset.PKID_PhysicalAsset, dbo.tbl_Operations.PKID_Operation
```

Also make sure that statistics on all tables are up to date. If your query would result in 0 rows returned, but the statistics are out of date, the query optimizer will do full table scan to be sure that it isn't returning an incorrect result.

Comment: Ah, so the where has to go before a group by. Will give it a whirl, ta!

Comment: Still timing out I'm afraid.

Comment: How many entries do you have in the tbl_Schedules with FKID_Operation = 1505? How does it compare to any other ids?

Comment: None, currently. Other times I've run it against FKID_Operations with no records it's come back straight away. It just seems that if we query 1505 (or higher) it's taking ages. In fact, I'd say that the higher the FKID_Operation is, the longer it takes, but 1505 is definitely where it seems to keel over and die.

Comment: Oh, so you are trying to inner join an id that isn't in the table, and thus should return 0 rows? 

If the statistics for the index are too far out of date, it will cause the SQL server to perform a full table scan to be certain that it isn't missing anything. In that case do an UPDATE STATISTICS on tbl_Schedules

Comment: Brilliant, that did the job. Did the UPDATE STATISTICS on all three tables (it actually seemed to be the tbl_Operations that was acting slow, once I did it on that it was practically instantaneous). Now how do I put this as the answer? Maybe you should put it separately and I'll accept it?

Comment: Added the statistics part as part of the answer. So now you can accept the current one. :-)